# inserted points not visible of inserts made after drop series in influxDB

Tags: influxdb

I am using InfluxDB 0.13 on CentOS (centos-release-7-2.1511.el7.centos.2.10.x86_64) and I observed certain anomalous behavior which I could not understand, would appreciate if anyone could provide an explanation to this.

I inserted some data to a measurement in Line format using admin UI. Say:

```
test_ms,host=host3 value=10
test_ms,host=host3 value=20
```

The following query works correctly in shell and gives following output:

```
select * from test_ms
```

```
name: test_ms
-------------
time                    host    value
1472809745694769849     host3   10
1472809749918219715     host3   20
```

Now I drop the series test_ms using below and check if for points

```
drop series from test_ms

select * from test_ms
```

There are no results returned as expected.

However any new entries made afterwards (through admin UI) succeeds but does not show up in subsequent select queries.

```
test_ms,host=host3 value=30
test_ms,host=host3 value=40

select * from test_ms ===> No results returned !
```

Why is such behavior exhibited ?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in the `0.13` version. If you bounce your process the query should work.

Please upgrade to `1.0+`.

Comment: Thank you I shall upgrade and give it a try.